# Creation of Lists with different sizes inside a list - Main list with sublists and subsub lists inside

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, java-8

Basically I am trying to obtain prices of a particular application  for 7 different dates , sort the dates in ascending order and re-assign the corresponding prices with new sorted dates.

So, I want to create a main list with sublists inside something like 
`[[Dates], [sorted Dates], [[pricesOfDay1],[pricesOfDay2],[pricesOfDay3]]]` in java8.

I am able to create

```
[[Dates], [sorted_Dates], [pricesOfDay1,pricesOfDay2,pricesOfDay3]]
```

by using

```
List<List<String>> ListOfTariffSlots = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

But is it possible to create separate list for each day prices but still inside a list? I don't want all the prices as elements in a single list. I want them as elements of a sublists but inside a list.

I hope this is now clear. Kindly let me know if more is required.
All possible suggestions are welcome

Comment: You can use a Map with a key pointing over to the date and a value of List containing the prices. Yet your question is not very clear. I suppose you need to update it.

Comment: This looks like it would be better to write a class with the appropriate fields instead.

Comment: How deep can your subsub list thing ? Is there a limit ?

Comment: The signature of List<List<String>> ListOfTariffSlots = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); can not hold the structure you are describing. You need List<List<Object>> ListOfTariffSlots = new ArrayList<List<Object>>(); Where the Object is either a String or a List<String>

Comment: Subsublist should be for 7 days. i.e, The main list should contain 3 lists. First element with list of dates (sublist1), second element with list of sorted dates (sublist2) , third element (i.e.,sublist3) with subsublists of prices of 7 days, i.e., day1 prices as first subsublist, day2 prices as second subsublist and so on..

Comment: @Priya is this List<> structure a Must or you can replace it with Object model ?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I already tried List<List<Object>> ListOfTariffSlots = new ArrayList<List<Object>>(); . But it does not accept to add List<String>. It is not a must to be List<> structure. But I get the data in Strings. So I get to store it in list of String.

Comment: Write the line you use to insert the List<String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. But it was still not as expected. I have created a logic I guess this is similar with my requrement.
I have now created a list of prices as :

```
List<Object> priceList = null;
```

then in every date, which I did in a loop, I instantiated price list as

```
priceList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

and then in every list of the loop where I extracted prices for a particular day, I added it to the main priceList Object

```
priceList.add(price);

for(Element el : PriceLabels) {
//do something
//extract "price" list
}
```

In the above line, "price" is a list and "priceList" is also a list. That is, a list(priceList) holding another list(price). 
Then in the final step, I added this "priceList" to the superlist "ListOfTariffSlots".

```
ListOfTariffSlots.addAll((Collection<? extends List<Object>>) priceList);
```

I think this works for the requirement. I understand that it was not very clear for many of you. But thank you all for all your suggestions. It helped me to come up with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is according to the qualities you have specified:

- The TreeMap is ordered
- it contains all dates in ordered form
- And you have the Lists of the prices on per day basis.

> private TreeMap<< Date ,Price> pricesPerDate

If you must hold your data in this strange list. Something i don't recommend you can easily convert this TreeMap structure into:

```
 List<List<Object>> ListOfTariffSlots
```

Notice that here we use Object and not String because there is no way to have three levels of lists with your original signature.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you clear, what you need is a recursive data structure, like a `b-tree`.  Where you have as `values` a list of strings, and as `subLists` a list of `ListNode` class.

```
class ListNode {
    List<String> values;
    List<ListNode> subLists;
}
```

An example how can you create your desired result

```
 ListNode pricesOfDay1 = new ListNode();
 pricesOfDay1.values = Arrays.asList("pricesOfDay1");
 ListNode pricesOfDay2 = new ListNode();
 pricesOfDay2.values = Arrays.asList("pricesOfDay2");
 ListNode pricesOfDay3 = new ListNode();
 pricesOfDay3.values = Arrays.asList("pricesOfDay3");

 ListNode priceOfDays = new ListNode();
 priceOfDays.subLists = Arrays.asList(pricesOfDay1, pricesOfDay2, pricesOfDay3);

 ListNode sortedDates = new ListNode();
 sortedDates.values = Arrays.asList("sorted_Dates");

 ListNode dates = new ListNode();
 dates.values = Arrays.asList("dates");

 ListNode rootList = new ListNode();

 rootList.subLists = Arrays.asList(dates, sortedDates, priceOfDays);
```

You can just use a simple tree traversal to go through every sublist and print the values.

Leaves will have a null `subList` variable, where any parent will have a null `values` variable.